# how to set an parameter to not filter the SQL query when not set

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page with a list of artists and three buttons; photographers, makeup artists, all

I want to query the database to select each type through $_GET when any of the buttons is clicked which is easy for the first two I can set the url to ?type=photographers

however when I want to set the type to all, there's no value in the type column called all, i tried to set the type to * but it doesn't work

```
SELECT name, location, score, type FROM artists WHERE type = ?
```

how to set type to show all what should the variable be equal to?

edit: I'm already using the !empty method, now I want to add more rules to my query and it's getting complicated, any other solution where I don't have to have two queries in the if and else?

Comment: Just don't add `WHERE ...` to you sql-query.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have two choices,
1. Create your base sql query `SELECT name, location, score, type FROM artists` and append where clause based on the type (If type is ALL do not append the clause).
2. When click ALL, really pass the all types (photographers, makeup artists) and check for
 `WHERE type IN ()`;

Comment: in the first option, how do I stop the query to type some php that would return where only when there's a type, can you give me an example of how to put php in the middle of sql?

Comment: I am sorry, not familiar with PHP syntax, that why just suggested the idea instead of writing the scripts. Although does not seems tough to check the value on click event  and updating the sql statement and executing it. May be i am guessing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $cond = 1;
 if(!empty($_GET)){
    $cond = ' type = '.$_GET['your-query-string'];
 }

 SELECT name, location, score, type FROM artists WHERE $cond
```

Comment: `WHERE 1`? Seriously?

Comment: Second question - sql-injection. You know what is it?

Comment: I'm already using the !empty method, now I want to add more rules to my query and it's getting complicated, any other solution where I don't have to have two queries in the if and else?

Comment: @Krim simply build your where statement and bind values if the params are set. If no params are set, it will return everything (since there wont be any where)

Comment: @Krim Yes, I'm sure. If it returns errors, you've obviously done something wrong, though.

Comment: it gave me an error '
Parse error
: syntax error, unexpected '" LIMIT ?, ?"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in
F:\xampp\htdocs\fetch_pages.php
on line 25'

The code '$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, location, score, img, id, type FROM artists WHERE type = "" LIMIT ?, ?");'

Answer (score 0):

Just do a condition on your $_GET and change your SQL query accordingly. If you want to select all your entries, you don't need WHERE.

Answer (score -1):

The following code block will do across the issue you are facing:

```
$query = "SELECT name, location, score, type FROM artists";
if(!empty($_GET)) {
    $whereArgs = "WHERE type = ".$_GET['your-query-string'];
}
// Run your query using `$query` here.
```

Comment: This suggestion is _dangerous_. Do _not_ do it this way. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries.